# Not sure if I should use a cursor in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

I have a problem here. The thing is that I have a table called `MOSTEP`, in this table there's a column called `MOID`. What I need to do is to check repeated values, what I mean by this is for example, in the table there are these values:

```
10, 9, 8, 6, 9, 5, 2 10
```

I need to check all the values of `MOID` in the table and then do 2 things, the details of the conditions are rather irrelevant to this questions so I'll omit them:

1. if the value only appears once, I do something with each of them.
2. If the value appears more than once, I do something else with each of them.

I know how to check for repeated and not repeated values using

```
COUNT(MOID)
```

However I don't know how to check for this in a same query and make it efficient.

I was thinking in using two cursors, one that stores all the repeated values and then just fetch each row, and another that does the same thing but with the non repeated values. But I've heard that cursors are not always the best option

I was also thinking in doing `IF` or `CASE` conditions within a `SELECT` but I'm not really sure how of to do it.

If someone could help me I'll really appreciate it

Comment: Cursors are **very rarely** even necessary, and never really a good choice - only a last resort, if nothing else works.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't sound like there's any reason to use a cursor for this.
You can use `COUNT()` with `OVER()` and `CASE` efficiently:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *,COUNT(MOID) OVER(PARTITION BY MOID) MOID_CT
              FROM MOSTEP)
SELECT MOID
      ,CASE WHEN MOID_CT = 1 THEN 'Something' ELSE 'SomethingElse' END
FROM cte
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a22f/2/0)

Comment: Holly mother of god, Thnx mate you saved me